# Delphi: "too many actual parameters" error when calling Delete(...) for splitting string

Tags: delphi, split, delphi-7

Im getting the error of too many actual parameters

```
Procedure TSub.ReadUsers;
var
  iPos , i : integer;
begin
  ReadLine;
  iPos := 0;
  for i := 1 to Counter do
    iPos := pos('#',sLine);
  arrUsers[i] := copy(sLine, 1, ipos-1);
  delete(sLine,1,iPos);//error in this line
  iPos := pos('#',sLine);
end;
```

Comment: You need a `begin` and `end` around your `for..do` loop (with the `end;` probably just before the final `end;` in the procedure). Otherwise, you're just setting `iPos` to the same value again and again (it's not processing the array items, calling `Delete`, and resetting `iPos` to a new value) like I think you intend it to do.

Comment: The final assignment to iPos is pointless

Comment: Thanks man will check it out and let u know

Comment: @David, read my comment. :-) There should be a `begin..end` surrounding the two lines that assign to `iPos` (IOW, after the `for` and before the final `end;`).

Comment: Even then, AFAICT, it would still be pointless, as the assignment is done in the beginning of the next iteration of the loop anyway. But there should probably be a check for iPos being 0 and then ending the loop.

Comment: FWIW, that can't cause the error message. The code looks wrong, indeed, but that is not the cause for the compile-time error message.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, the compile time error is a scope issue, mentioned in the answer below. (It should be `System.Delete`; the error being caused is because a different `Delete` is apparently in scope. The discussion of the missing begin..end and the loop not working as intended is extraneous to the actual question (it's a bonus points issue). :-)

Comment: Well, maybe he reserved arrUsers[0] for always being empty string ?
I'd be more concerned with High(appUsers) be never less than Counter.

...and all this function instead one-liner call of Split :-)

BTW, did D7 had PosEx(...) or it only introduced later ? D5 for i remember had not.

Comment: @Rudy: You're right (and so is David). The final assignment to `iPos` is indeed extraneous, of course. I was focused more on the missing begin/end pair to examine exactly what that line was doing. :-)

Answer (score 15):

Without seeing the rest of the code or knowing what version of Delphi you're using, your call to Delete is probably not referencing `System.Delete` (you may have another `Delete` method in scope, possibly in the class `TSub`).  Trying using the following instead and see if that clears it up:

```
System.Delete(sLine,1,iPos);
```

Comment: Also, I don't see `sLine` declared anywhere... assuming that's a boo-boo in posting the code.

Comment: Wil try that im using delphi 7 and let u know!

Comment: @user1618040 then you should tag your question with Delphi version tag! Also - deleting part of the string from the beginning is copying all the rest characters from end to the start. It is VERY inefficient way to parse the string. You'd better delete from end. And most proper way is to delete-nothing and no-copy-to-itself. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954711/how-can-i-loop-through-a-delimited-string-and-assign-the-contents-of-the-string/11955009#answer-11955009 and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm